# c:\ to mysql> mode in command promt

Tags: mysql, command-line

I am trying to check `mysql` status for my system.

I understand that from command prompt my mode should be `mysql>` so I could enter

```
mysql>status;
```

how do I navigate from my `c:\Documents and Settings\etc...` to read as `mysql>` mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming login by root:

```
<MYSQL_DIR>\bin\mysql.exe -uroot -p
```

Comment: This worked gr8. But please explain what are we doing by executing the file and why we suffix with -uroot -p. What does these command do?

Comment: @oneofthelions we run external console program `mysql.exe`. It's client for the RDMS MySQL. We passed user login (`root`) as parameter.

Comment: And my configuration reads as
server characteristics: latin1
db characteristics    : latin1. How do I change them to utf8 encoding?

Comment: @oneofthelions `mysql> charset utf8`

Comment: only client and conn characteristics are changed to utf8. Server and DB, can they be changed too to `utf8` too? What is the difference in all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting-disconnecting.html